Retrieving Specific Fundamental Data Across Specific Date Range
I am attempting to retrieve specific fundamental data associated with US companies (example AAPL) and be able to represent the data by financial quarter.
The following works and I can access a time series dataset:
cN = FinancialData["Apple", "Name"];
c = Interpreter["Company"][cN];

(*Specify start and end dates*)
sD = DateObject["2020"];
eD = DateObject["2023"];

fd = EntityValue[c, 
  EntityProperty["Company", 
   "TotalRevenue", {"Date" -> Interval[{sD, eD}], 
    "TimeSeriesType" -> "Annual"}]];

The following does not work and no dataset is returned that represents a collection of timeseries data associated with each provided property.
(*Specify the property of interest,e.g.,Revenue or Net Income*)
p = CanonicalName /@ {EntityProperty["Company", 
     "CashAndCashEquivalents"], 
    EntityProperty["Company", "WorkingCapital"], 
    EntityProperty["Company", "TotalRevenue"], 
    EntityProperty["Company", "LongTermDebt"], 
    EntityProperty["Company", "TotalLiabilities"]};

EntityValue[c, 
 EntityProperty["Company", 
  p, {"Date" -> Interval[{sD, eD}], "TimeSeriesType" -> "Annual"}]]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Is there an alternative way to obtain a table of properties against their values across a specified timeframe (annually/quarterly).
Thanks in advance!
M.

I'm leaving this as a comment link to an example notebook I made for now because I'm not 100% sure this is what you want. Is it something like this?

I believe this is what you want. We first specify the name of the company and date bounds like you have done
c = Interpreter["Company"][cN];

(*Specify date range*)
sD = DateObject["2020"];
eD = DateObject["2023"];
dates = DateRange[sD, eD, Quantity[1, "year"]];

Then create a list of the properties we want:
(*specify target properties*)
propertiesWanted = {"CashAndCashEquivalents", "WorkingCapital", 
   "TotalRevenue", "LongTermDebt", "TotalLiabilities"};

Then create a list of property arguments to supply to our "Company" entity. Here I specify quarterly for the date granularity
propertyArgsList = 
  EntityProperty[
     "Company", #, {"Date" -> Interval[{sD, eD}], 
      "TimeSeriesType" -> "Quarterly"}] & /@ propertiesWanted;

And now grab the data at those quarterly time intervals. These will come out as TimeSeries objects
timeSeriesDATA = c[propertyArgsList];

If you just want a table of the data, you can get the DatePath of each TimeSeries:
#["DatePath"] & /@ timeSeriesDATA

Or to create a nice table:
dates = timeSeriesDATA[[1]]["Dates"];
dates = DateString[#, {"YearShort", "/", "QuarterNameShort"}] & /@ 
  dates
vals = #["Values"] & /@ timeSeriesDATA // Transpose;

tableRows = MapThread[Join[{#1}, #2] &, {dates, vals}];
headers = Join[{"Year/Quarter"}, propertiesWanted];
tableRows = Prepend[tableRows, headers];
Grid[tableRows, 
 Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
     Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
 Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
    Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
    Darker[Gray, .6]}}]



Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Appreciate the assist!
